# How can i echo error for registration system to another index file

Tags: php, echo, registration

I'm trying to echo registration system errors to the main index.php file, but I'm doing something wrong. Can someone please explain what I've been doing wrong and how to do it right?

index.php file.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include "config.php"; 

?>

<div class="container">
<h1>Registration</h1>

<?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

    <form action="main.php" method="post">
        <p>Username: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off"></p>
        <p>Password: </p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"></p>
        <p><button name="send" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Send</button></p>
    </form>

</div>
</div>
```

main.php file..

```
    <?php 
include "config.php";

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST(md5['password']);

    if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $error = "Username is empty<br/>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Password is empty";
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO register(username,password) VALUES('$username', '$password')")
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Registred";
}

$_SESSION['error'] = $error;

?>
```

Comment: You must unset your session variable after printing the error message. Otherwise it will show the error message whenever you visit index.php. or you can assign $_SESSION['error']=null , if your main.php evaluates user input without any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$error is not defined.

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['error'];?>
```

or modify your index.php file as below

```
<?php 
session_start();
include "config.php"; 
// added this line to your code
$error = (isset($_SESSION['error'])) ? $_SESSION['error'] : "";
?>

<div class="container">
<h1>Registration</h1>

<?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

    <form action="main.php" method="post">
        <p>Username: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off"></p>
        <p>Password: </p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"></p>
        <p><button name="send" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Send</button></p>
    </form>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then do var_dump($_SESSION['error']); and post the result

Comment: Returned result   NULL

Comment: You haven't used session_start() on main.php. Use session_start() on main.php or add session_start(); to config.php. I recommend the second option.

Comment: Thank you it works now. One more question, after i submit button its redirect me to main.php and after i go back its display errors. i Think my structure of registration code is not correct, i think need to  add  some else statement before $query goes.

Answer (score 0):

if there is an error, the mysql query with no values will return an error 
too, the code

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

prevents any code after it from being executed thus it returns no result.
try removing that part first.